# Trying to offer user the chance to restart a program by calling a function but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, restart

I'm working on a little python calculator and once it has run, I want to ask the user if they want to start again, and then restart the program based on their response.

I have this:

```py
def begin():
    print("WELCOME TO THE PYTHON CALCULATOR\n\nYOUR SELECTIONS:\nBasic (+, -, *, /)\nAdvanced (power, square root)\nBMI\nMortgage\nTrip\n")
    selection = input("What type of Calculator would you like to use? (NB: Case sensitive): ")

    if selection == "Basic":
        basic_input()
    if selection == "Advanced":
        adv_input()
    if selection == "BMI":
        imp_or_met = input("Do you prefer to use metric or imperial units? (Metric/Imperial): ")
        if imp_or_met == "Metric":
            bmi_met()
        elif imp_or_met == "Imperial":
            bmi_imp()
    if selection == "Mortgage":
        mort_calc()
    if selection == "Trip":
        trip_calc()

begin()
#restart calculator
restart = print(input("Would you like to use the calculator again?\n1: Yes, 2: No\n"))
if restart == "1":
    begin()
else:
    print("Thank you for using the calculator!")
```

But this is the output (from the question asking user whether they want to start again):

> *Would you like to use the calculator again?
>
> 1: Yes, 2: No
>
> 1
>
> Thank you for using the calculator!*

I'm VERY new to coding so I appreciate this might seem like a very trivial question :)... but I appreciate any help here!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can we see your full code? Especially the part where you ask the user for input to restart.

Comment: The shown snippet is too short. Show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the question.

Comment: Don't show the full code! Just a mock up of the bit where you do the prompt. But it has be runnable by us so we can test and offer suggestions.

Comment: `restart` is always `None` in your code, the return value of the unnecessary `print()` you did.

Comment: You are printing the input statement, while the print statement itself returns None. That's why it just repeats the user input while your if condition always remains false for that reaoson. Start to remove the print() around the input() function.

Comment: As a general tip, when variables don't compare the way you expect, print out what that are. You could add `print(repr(restart))` before the compare and see if it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
restart = input("Would you like to use the calculator again?\n1: Yes, 2: No\n")

if restart == "1":
    begin()
else:
    print("Thank you for using the calculator!")
```

The problem is you are assigning `print(input(...))` to `restart`, which is `NoneType`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this

```
def begin():
    #code for your begin() function
    #by adding restart code here you can restart the function as many times as you want
    restart = int(input("Would you like to use the calculator again?\n1: Yes, 2: No\n"))

    if restart == 1:
        begin()
    else:
        print("Thank you for using the calculator!")
        SystemExit(0) #To exit from the program

if __name__ == '__main__':
   begin()
```

Comment: This has a couple of problems. It asks the question on the first run and since it keeps calling itself, it will eventually hit a python recursion error. And if the user enters a non-integer, the program will exit with an exception instead of asking again.

Comment: As mentioned by @tdelaney: you'll facing infinite loop. Not good.

Comment: @dboy , tdelaney, can you suggest any other method to keep the program running without getting into an infinite loop

Comment: You've got a good idea here in general. Instead of the code calling itself, how about a `while` outside of the function. It would call `begin()` and do the problem when that function returns. If the user doesn't enter "1", then break. Put the goodbye message after the while and you' ve got it.